# LinkedIn doesn't fetch metadata when sharing website

Tags: html, share, linkedin-api, facebook-opengraph, meta-tags

I'm having issues with sharing a website I'm working on on LinkedIn: LinkedIn doesn't fetch any data from the page. The site's metadata follows the recommendations in [their docs](https://help.linkedin.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/46687/~/making-your-website-shareable-on-linkedin). I tried all [these suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18468892/linkedin-sharing-urls-not-parsing-open-graph).

In addition, I investigated the following:

1. Serving content over HTTP instead of HTTPS, but a lot of other sites served over HTTPS, such as https://stripe.com/no and https://www.facebook.com/, work perfectly fine.
2. Posting as a company page. This didn't make any difference, other than allowing manual data entry (which is handy as a makeshift solution).
3. Posting as a different user. Didn't make any difference.
4. Posting new content on the website to make sure that the metadata hadn't been cached by LinkedIn. This also didn't make any difference.
5. This was also a problem before I added the Open Graph meta tags.

[This might be a problem caused by LinkedIn](http://community.linkedin.com/questions/366244/my-og-meta-tag-for-image-is-not-working-2.html), but – considering that this works for other sites – I'm open to the possibility that I'm the one doing something wrong.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: @Thijs I don't quite remember, but I think it started working after a while.

Answer (score 9):

I don't think you will see any changes in the data that LinkedIn grabs from your website for about a week:

> The first time that LinkedIn's crawlers visit a webpage when asked to share content via a URL, the data it finds (Open Graph values or our own analysis) will be cached for a period of approximately 7 days.
>
> This means that if you subsequently change the article's description, upload a new image, fix a typo in the title, etc., you will not see the change represented during any subsequent attempts to share the page until the cache has expired and the crawler is forced to revisit the page to retrieve fresh content.

https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/share-on-linkedin (scroll to the bottom)

Comment: I already tried publishing new content, so the caching shouldn't be an issue. (See point 4 above.)

Comment: well, it seems to be a known issue with LinkedIn. Likely that they haven't corrected. My website link is not updated even after 3 weeks. Only way for me was to modify the url a little by appending a get parameter. https://test.com/?1 
Let me know if there is alternate solution

Answer (score 1):

In my case it seemed that LinkedIn Parser is really poor to the point that if your HTML file doesn't have the `<head>` tag (which is not required by the spec) It will simply ignore everything where the bellow wouldn't work

```
<!doctype html>
<meta charset=utf-8>                                                            
<meta property=og:title content='My Shared Article Title'>                      
<meta property=og:description content='Description of shared article'>          
<meta property=og:image content=http://i.imgur.com/12345.jpg>                
<meta name=description content='Nice description'>
<title>TEST 15</title>
<p>content here</p>
```

But simply adding the opening `<head>` tag (still valid HTML), did the trick

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8>                                                            
<meta property=og:title content='My Shared Article Title'>                      
<meta property=og:description content='Description of shared article'>          
<meta property=og:image content=http://i.imgur.com/12345.jpg>                
<meta name=description content='Nice description'>
<title>TEST 15</title>
<p>content here</p>
```

Comment: you shout close the head after the title and add a body tag before your first content!

Comment: It’s actually fine to omit the closing tag, @PhilipMiglinci. (Though the advantage of saving a couple of bytes is rather trivial.)

Comment: Ran into this recently where my site's minifier had a flag on that stripped out "unnecessary" tags that aren't in the official html spec, so <head> was getting removed. Turned off the flag and worked instantly.

Answer (score 1):

As in all things programming, let's *first* look at the **[Official LinkedIn Sharing Documentation](https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/answer/46687/making-your-website-shareable-on-linkedin?lang=en)**!  The LinkedIn share API will respect the following `og:` tags in your HTML...

- `<meta property='og:title' content='Title of the article"/>`
- `<meta property='og:image' content='//media.example.com/ 1234567.jpg"/>`
- `<meta property='og:description' content='Description that will show in the preview"/>`
- `<meta property='og:url' content='//www.example.com/URL of the article" />`

Want to be sure you're using it right?  That's easy -- check out the **[Official LinkedIn Post Inspector](https://www.linkedin.com/post-inspector/)** to have your share URL debugged, checked, and verified.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the exact same issue. Clear your cache history. Then add this 'prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#'" to each metadata tag, and it will work immediately:

```
    <meta prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#" property='og:title' content='Content Title'/>
    <meta prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#" property='og:image' content='https://images.url...'/>
    <meta prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#" property='og:description' content='Description'/>
    <meta prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#" property='og:url' content='https://site_url/'/>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will fix it for you just enter your website into here and it seems to clear their cache which in my case was about 3 years old cache ???

https://www.linkedin.com/post-inspector/inspect/

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was an `og:url` tag that always contained the value of the root domain:

```
<meta property="og:url" content="https://example.com/">
```

This caused linkedin to always get and display the cached content of this root domain (*only* linkedin had this problem, it worked on every other site like facebook, whatsapp, instagram, ms teams, everything - that's why i was so confused).

As soon as i started overriding the `og:url` on each child page, issue was gone.

```
// page 1:
<meta property="og:url" content="https://example.com/page-11">
// page 2:
<meta property="og:url" content="https://example.com/page-2">
// etc.
```