# Wordpress Website Link Preview not working in LinkedIn Groups

Tags: linkedin-api, api-linkpreview

I want to share this article link (https://www.ngdevelop.tech/handsontable/) in the LinkedIn groups but the link preview is not working. This same thing happens for my previous two link share. Before the last two share, Link preview was working fine, but now it is not working.

When I checked the response from LinkedIn link preview service I got Error Code 500 for the link share in my status.

For Link share in group, I got below response : `{"data":[{"images":[],"id":"https://www.ngdevelop.tech/handsontable/?2","type":"UrlPreview","status":"FAILED"}],"meta":{},"id":"/communities-api/v1/url-preview/https%3A%2F%2Fwww.ngdevelop.tech%2Fhandsontable%2F%3F2"}`

This is my Open Graph Check https://opengraphcheck.com/result.php?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.ngdevelop.tech%2Fhandsontable%2F#.W0TlRNIzaM8

and social debug : https://socialdebug.com/results?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.ngdevelop.tech%2Fhandsontable%2F

I have also refered Stackoverflow 
: [LinkedIn doesn't fetch metadata when sharing website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35201679/linkedin-doesnt-fetch-metadata-when-sharing-website) post, and https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/answer/46687/making-your-website-shareable-on-linkedin?lang=en  but nothing worked.

Please help...

Answer (score 0):

I have been seeing this problem as well and have isolated what is going on.
Here is the behavior I have seen with LinkedIn recently when sharing pages from my WordPress.com site:
- Sharing in my own feed works with the content preview... sometimes.
- Sharing in a LinkedIn Group does not work at all. The LinkedIn XHR request that builds the preview actually returns a 500.

Using the [LinkedIn Post Inspector](https://www.linkedin.com/post-inspector/inspect) tool I was able to see that their crawler was hitting a redirect loop. They would request an HTTPS URL, get redirected to an HTTP URL, then get redirected to an HTTPS URL, on and on.

When browsing to the same pages with Safari or Chrome I was not redirected. Finally I tried the same using the user-agent of the LinkedIn crawler. Aha! That was the key. WordPress.com is treating the LinkedIn (and Facebook) user-agents differently and redirecting them into a loop.

Example using curl:

`curl -v -I -A 'LinkedInBot/1.0 (compatible; Mozilla/5.0; Jakarta Commons-HttpClient/3.1 +http://www.linkedin.com)' -k --http1.1 --header 'Host: yoursite.com'  'https://wordpress origin IPv4 address'`

After a week of back and forth with WordPress.com support they say now that this is *intentional*. The reason this redirect behavior is in place is that Facebook, LinkedIn, etc. count the number of times a URL is shared. And the redirect prevents these sites from counting an HTTPS URL separately from an HTTP URL for the same resource. Their redirect is an attempt to canonicalize the URL.

This sharing count "fix" is moot if the redirect prevents anyone from sharing the URL, which is where I am right now.

Good luck!