# Open Graph metadata not pulled through to LinkedIn or Twitter

Tags: wordpress, linkedin-api, facebook-opengraph, meta-tags

Having difficulty articulating this question, so your patience is much appreciated. Below is a link to one of my blog posts.  When I attempt to share this blog on Facebook (for example), the open graph meta tags are pulled through just fine.  When I attempt to share this link via linkedin, the title and link are pulled, but the blog thumbnail image fails to show up.

https://www.lightspeedmarketing.com/may-4th-musings-star-wars-day/

When I check the pagesource, I see that the meta tags are pulling all the correct data, and the image link is there:

```
<meta property="og:image" 
content="https://www.lightspeedmarketing.com/wp-
content/uploads/2017/05/Maythe4th_639x300.png"/>
```

I am using the WPSSO plugin for wordpress to help me with social tags.

I am happy to provide more context if I can.  Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Looks like you don't meet the requirements... https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/answer/46687/making-your-website-shareable-on-linkedin?lang=en

Comment: @brasofilo Thanks for the link! I've updated the image to meet those requirements, but still nothing. Is the problem that the image is being pulled from an https address?

Comment: There was a similar question earlier about Facebook not recognizing `og:image` when sharing a link, but I tested and it worked for me. I suppose it could be a cache issue. Try from another computer or share as another Linkedin user.

Comment: Here on the right column, we can see "Related questions", this one seems useful: [Linkedin sharing urls / not parsing open graph](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18468892/1287812)