# force linkedin to use custom thumbnail of wordpress post

Tags: php, wordpress, linkedin-api

I am using this in my functions.php

```
  add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails'); 
  set_post_thumbnail_size(); 

  add_image_size( 'post-thumb', 669, 272 );
```

and in my single.php,home.php and archive.php.. I am using this in loop:

```
   <?php the_post_thumbnail('post-thumb'); ?>
```

Now I when I share post to linkedin is used the thumbnail of 669 x 272 dimension but I want to make another custom size of  thumbnail e.g 180 x 110 size n force linkedin to use that thumbnail.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use OpenGraph tags to specify content for social media sites to pull from. [Documentation](http://ogp.me).

The OpenGraph tags must go in the `<head>`. You can make this dynamic by adding something like this to your `functions.php`:

```
function add_opengraph() {
    ?>
    <meta property="og:title" content="<?= get_the_title() ?>" />
    <meta property="og:image" content="<?= get_the_post_thumbnail_url( 'small-thumb' ) ?>" />
    <meta property="og:image:width" content="180" />
    <meta property="og:image:height" content="110" />
    <?php
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'add_opengraph' );
```

You will of course need to make another thumbnail size just as you did before.

```
add_image_size( 'small-thumb', 180, 110 );
```

Two other things you might try debugging:

1. Try checking with a new page, one that you haven't tested before. It's possible that LinkedIn is caching your old image.
2. Are you using HTTPS? According to [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18468892/linkedin-sharing-urls-not-parsing-open-graph#comment37121633_18494511) LinkedIn might have trouble crawling HTTPS urls.

Comment: I did create the other thumbnail size with this 'small-thumb' name but in browser source it's still showing the height of the previous one. my code is this in functions.php
`add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' ); 
set_post_thumbnail_size();
add_image_size( 'post-thumb', 669, 272, true );
add_image_size( 'small-thumb', 180, 110, true );

function add_opengraph() {
    ?>
    <meta property="og:title" content="<?= get_the_title() ?>" />
    <meta property="og:image" content="<?= get_the_post_thumbnail_url( 'small-thumb' ) ?>" />
    <?php
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'add_opengraph' );`

Comment: Can you try using Facebook's OpenGraph debugger to see what image they are pulling through? [Link here](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing).

Comment: Also you can check the page source, and see if the opengraph tags are showing up for your post.

Comment: I have Yoast SEO plugin installed.. n it's overriding the height of open graph image.. but it's now showing the height of og nor width when I deactivate my plugin.
and yes it's showing the title and image in open graph.. but not including height or width in meta property tags.

Comment: You can tell OpenGraph the expected size of the image. I updated my answer. Can you view page source, and confirm the url for the OpenGraph image is correct?

Comment: Yes I did the same n deactivated the YOAST too.. n url is correct and OpenGraph shows the updated width n height too..but when I share on linkedin.. it's now showing full image still.. cropped in half way n not showing some content.

Comment: I'm thinking it might be a caching issue with LinkedIn. Can you try testing this with a completely new page? *I updated my answer with this.